# Can I detect when a user moves through an intersection?

Tags: android, location, maps

I am in the process of planning an app that includes a feature that requires it to record and store the exact route a user takes while driving. Is there any location api that supports this out of the box? Or supports detecting a turn? I was initially hoping for an event triggered by the user turning onto a different road, but so far, no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this way:

1 Request for GPS location update every 30s ,you can do this with Timer and TimerTask ,and LocationManager;

2 You can get the road name through Google Map API with the GPS location you get;

3 So you will get to know whether the user is turning onto a different road every 30 seconds.

Comment: This is a method I had considered, and should work in most cases, but has a flaw involving the driver staying on curved roads for a long period of time.  [Crude MS Paint diagram here.](http://i.imgur.com/4zcGxxZ.png)

The red line represents the user's actual path, while the black line represents roads, and the blue line represents the path the app records. If the blue stars represent where the app detects a road change, then the best route between waypoints would be the wrong road, which breaks the app's functionality.

Comment: I have found what I think is a solution to the flaw in your method of finding the route, and have posted my own answer if you're interested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution that makes use of the other answer here. I will post it as a separate answer though as it adds more to the other answer and is a full solution.  As Ai Hao said, I could have my app request an updated location every 30 seconds to determine whether the user is on a new road, and then place a waypoint signalling the turn.  However, this method is flawed if the mapping algorithm used (and I do not have the expertise to write my own) detects multiple possible routes.  My solution to this issue is to store all location responses until a turn is made.  This means that when a turn is detected, the oldest location data will be the last turn, while the newest will correspond to the turn being made.  The app will request alternate routes, and if any are found, will calculate a route between the second oldest and second most recent coordinates, until no alternate routes are found. This should result in the exact route that the user took.